# Loading policy of arraylist elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a trouble. How does Java 7 handles elements loading from ArrayList? 
I try to be more clear: I get an ArrayList from my database. When I get it, are all of the bytes arrays stored in it loaded, or are them dynamically loaded only when I call get on them?

Comment: If you have an array with some values, ALL the values are in the memory (heap)

Comment: Yes, if I have an array, but if I have an arrayList?

Comment: Sorry you're talking about ArrayList. Yes, it's the same. Note that even if the reference of an array (or ArrayList) is in the stack (e.g. in a function), all the values are in the heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, internally, `ArrayList` actually uses `array` to store data.

```
 public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
     implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
 {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 8683452581122892189L;


/** The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored. 
 *  The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer. 
 */

 private transient Object[] elementData;
```

And yes, the data is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

All the objects in the list are already in the memory. Whole arraylist is populated with the elements you have retrieved through database. There is no such thing as dynamic loading of arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you are using for DB part. If you use tool like hibernate, this arraylist is loaded dynamically. To be clear when you say dynamically, it gets loaded when you try to access the arraylist but its loaded in one shoot even there(all bytes are populated). Arraylist internal uses arrays to manage collection of elements.

So, if you are using plain jdbc to fetch the records you must be populating the Arraylist yourself.There is nothing dynamic there.Bottom line, since it uses array inside, its as simple as populating an array.

Comment: I am using a non relational db: orientdb